# Creating Multiple Step Registration in iOS

Tags: ios, forms, uiscrollview, registration, pagecontrol

How to create a multiple step registration form in iOS. Which is the best way ?

Have around 5 steps in total. Two have just agree and disagree button . Everything else has prev and next and finally submit.

1) Creating separate controllers for each step ? Or
2) One controller with scrollview and page control and make it look like multiple steps ?

Second one is the easier one but can't find any tutorials or code to start with, Like to add next previous button in each views inside scrollview with different step actions, validations and many stuffs inside. Thinking of the code that will be real messy.

Have googled a lot but can't find any link for this idea..

Any links and codes are welcome..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When designing the UI for this don't think about the implementation details, first think about what is best for the user. After you have decided for a design approach think about how you can implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, from a UX standpoint I'd try to reduce the number of registration steps. On mobile devices, registration should be short and painless. Cut out all steps that aren't absolutely necessary and capture the bare minimum data to get a user started.

For your agree/disagree steps, I would look into whether modifying the EULA might help you remove those steps. Or you may already be covered using Apple's standard EULA.

If you're new to iOS programming, #1 is my recommendation IF you still need a multi-step process after stripping out unnecessary data registration fields. With separate view controllers, you can take advantage of storyboards, make it easier to validate data at each step, and enable you to add, remove and/or reorder registration steps fairly quickly.